# var keyword not recognized in JDK 11.0.15 in Eclipse 19-03

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, var

I am using Eclipse 19-03 with jre 11.0.15 , able to compile and run my other existing projects with jre 11 but in a project where var is being used (this project is deployed in server and running fine from months) my IDE gives an error "'var' is not allowed here". I have checked compiler it is jdk 11. In pom below entries are there.Not sure what I am missing. Can somebody please help.

```
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

[image]

```
  @Component
  public class StudentImpl implements StudentMapper {

  @Override
  public student mapObject(Address sourceObject) {
     if (sourceObject == null) {
  return null;
 }

var student = new student();

student.setFirstName(sourceObject.getFirstName());
student.setMiddleName(sourceObject.getMiddleName());
student.setLastName(sourceObject.getLastName());
student.setSuffix(sourceObject.getSuffix());
student.setCompany(sourceObject.getCompany());
student.setAddressLine1(sourceObject.getAddressLine1());
student.setAddressLine2(sourceObject.getAddressLine2());
student.setAddressLine3(sourceObject.getAddressLine3());
student.setCity(sourceObject.getCity());
student.setState(sourceObject.getState());
student.setZipCode(sourceObject.getZipCode());
student.setCountry(sourceObject.getCountry());
student.setDayPhone(sourceObject.getDayPhone());
student.setMobilePhone(sourceObject.getMobilePhone());
student.setTitle(sourceObject.getTitle());
student.setEMailID(sourceObject.getEMailID());
student.setDayFaxNo(sourceObject.getDayFaxNo());
student.setJobTitle(sourceObject.getJobTitle());

return student;
}
}
```

Comment: What is set for the compliance level in the "Java Compiler" page of the Eclipse project Properties? That is what tells Eclipse what level to check.

Comment: Does it complain about *every* `var` or just some? Java 11 introduced `var` in lambda arguments and I'm not aware of a later change, but maybe I missed something?

Comment: Yes, show us one of the errors, you can't use var everywhere.

Comment: @greg-449 this issue is with my system only , this code is old and deployed in server from years.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes everywhere

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Your code example seems to be broken. I guess you mean Eclipse 2019-03, which is almost 4 years and 15 releases behind. So please upgrade.

Comment: You also need to have the source level of the compiler to 11 or later

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have set the compiler to 11 only in Project->Properties.

Comment: So, can you reproduce it it the a current Eclipse instead of the pretty outdated version 2019-03 (it might caused by an issue already been fixed long time ago or by running Eclipse with a Java version newer than your Eclipse you missed to upgrade for years)? Please make sure your software you are using is up to date before asking (there is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/)). Why did you set manually _Project > Properties_ rather than right-click the project and choose _Maven > Update Project..._?